# What do new Overdraft rules for U.S. banks mean for transactions, when they go into effect July 1, 2010?

Tags: united-states, debit-card, overdraft

The rules will affect ATM withdrawals and debit card transactions, and are meant to protect consumers with an opt-in option.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

Previously, banks would allow you to overdraft your account, and then because you over-drafted, they would hit you with their large fees.  My bank was $29 per overdraft last I checked.

Now, they are not allowed to let you overdraft unless you explicitly ask.  I think the idea is that since most folks won't purposely overdraft very often, they would rather be declined the purchase than pay a $29 fee.

Imagine if you overdraft your account buying $75 worth of groceries.  The fee just made your bill $100 and you probably didn't know.  However if you were declined, then you would have the option to just take things out of your cart, buy the $40 in groceries you can afford.

The banks hold the position that if you are lost on a dark lonely road and the tow truck guy will take your debit card, if you can't overdraft you can't get a tow home.  They call it a favor to you.  I disagree.

Comment: I'm torn on this. The NCUA (National Credit Union Association) is a staunch opponent of this regulation and they are non-profits owned by their customers. I generally trust their opinion on such things because they don't have the same profit motivations as commercial banks. Check out this link: http://www.atfcu.org/index.php/component/content/article/227

Comment: Are they taking issue with the whole legislation, not just the overdraft part I think YMCbuzz was asking about?  I have read lots of debate about being regulated to much, and I lean towards regulation I agree it is best to go slow an measured.  I have sat here for 30 minutes reading and thinking and I am still unable to decidedly choose.

Comment: @JohnFx: I would think that the most helpful behavior would be to have a bank-by-phone procedure to request credit advances, so if someone really needed a cash advance (tow-truck situation) they could accept such a thing with full awareness of the fees involved.